# Array Equality Check Method

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop, return

I have a method to check whether two arrays are equal.

```
private bool CheckArray(int[] ilk_dizi, int[] son_dizi)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (ilk_dizi[i]==son_dizi[i])
        {
            if (i==4)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but i have a "not all code returs value" error. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the possibility of a "no return"
Be wary when using continue, alot of times it is not really necessary.

Try optimising your code as follows

```
private bool CheckArray(int[] ilk_dizi, int[] son_dizi)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       if (ilk_dizi[i]!=son_dizi[i])
       {
           return false;
       }
   }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `continue` inside one of the `else` blocks - and static analizer cannot infer arrays passed in are 5 long and that `i=4` will eventually be reached.

Imagine you passed two equal arrays size 2 each - then you will hit `continue` twice and exit the `for` loop - what will be returned then? Thus the warning.

Either put `return true;` at the end of method's body, or revise your algorithm.